# Regex in python that finds the attribute of some HTML tag?

Tags: python, regex, beautifulsoup

I've been trying to generate a working regex that finds attributes of html tags for
a while now but they all seem to fail one way or another.

Using regex because loading beautifulsoup takes too long for just checking one html tag.

Here is an example of the tag/property which needs to be checked:

```
<meta content="http://domain.com/path/path/file.jpg" rnd_attr="blah blah"      
   property="og:image"/>
```

How could a regex retrieve the content of this tag while making sure that the tag is of "og:image".

Sorry if this question is a bit naive or if its totally unfeasibly hard to generate the regex.

BONUS: Aside from BeautifulSoup, what other fast / working alternatives for DOM parserish things are there in python?

Thanks.

Comment: Instead of BeautifulSoup or regex, the best way seems to use lxml and his XPath capabilities.

Comment: Ah alright, I guess a followup question would be: Why is BeautifulSoup so popular/widely used if lxml is faster? Is it fewer functionalities?

Comment: The hard part is trying to figure out what exactly you're trying to accomplish. Please try to be clearer and more specific. By "content of this tag" do you mean the value of the **content** property or everything in the tag? By "making sure that the tag is of og:image" do you mean specifically that it has a **property** attribute whose value is "og:image"? Will the regex be checking one tag at a time, or retrieving the "content" of all the tags in a page that meet the criteria?

Comment: It's not that it's hard to generate the regex, it's just that the regex will be ridiculously complex and still won't parse the HTML correctly for every case. Regex is the wrong tool for parsing and extracting data from arbitrary HTML.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Description

This expression will

- find the meta tag which has an attribute `property="og:image"`
- avoid some really difficult edge cases
- capture the value of the content attribute
- allow the attributes to appear in any order

`<meta(?=\s|>)(?=(?:[^>=]|='[^']*'|="[^"]*"|=[^'"][^\s>]*)*?\sproperty=(?:'og:image|"og:image"|og:image))(?=(?:[^>=]|='[^']*'|="[^"]*"|=[^'"][^\s>]*)*?\scontent=('[^']*'|"[^"]*"|[^'"][^\s>]*))(?:[^'">=]*|='[^']*'|="[^"]*"|=[^'"][^\s>]*)*>`

[image]

## Example

In this live example, note the difficult edge case in the first two meta tag sample text:  http://www.rubular.com/r/YY70uaGPLE

**Sample Text**

```
<meta info=' content="DontFindMe" ' content="http://domain.com/path/path/file1.jpg" random_attr="blah blah"      
   property="og:image"/>
<meta content="http://domain.com/path/path/file2.jpg" random_attr="blah blah"      
   property="og:image"/>
<meta random_attr="blah blah"   property='og:image' content="foo'"   />
```

**Matches**

```
[0][0] = <meta info=' content="DontFindMe" ' content="http://domain.com/path/path/file1.jpg" random_attr="blah blah"      
   property="og:image"/>
[0][1] = "http://domain.com/path/path/file1.jpg"


[1][0] = <meta content="http://domain.com/path/path/file2.jpg" random_attr="blah blah"      
   property="og:image"/>
[1][1] = "http://domain.com/path/path/file2.jpg"


[2][0] = <meta random_attr="blah blah"   property='og:image' content="foo'"   />
[2][1] = "foo'"
```

Comment: It won't handle `<meta property='og:image' content="foo'" />` due both to the single quoted `property` attribute and the single quote in `content`.

Comment: @Blender, Look again.

Comment: @Denomales: But now it matches the quotes surrounding the attribute value.

Comment: Yes it did that before too.

Answer (score 2):

Have you actually benchmarked it and found that BeautifulSoup was the bottleneck?

```
content = soup.find('meta', property='og:image').get('content')
```

You could also use [lxml](http://lxml.de/), which is much faster:

```
import lxml.html

root = lxml.html.fromstring(html)  # Use .parse() on a file-like object instead

content = root.xpath('/html/head/meta[@property="og:image"][1]/@content')
```

Comment: thanks for reffing lxml. If it's much faster how come BS is so popular? Is it due to fewer features?

Comment: @LucasOu-Yang In my opinion, I use BeautifulSoup because of it's very simple syntax.

Comment: @LucasOu-Yang: It's easier to use.

Answer (score 0):

With [Scrapy](http://scrapy.org/):

```
sel = Selector(response)
fb_description = sel.xpath('//meta[@property="og:description"]/@content').extract()
```